# Simultaneously executing a loop and a function in Python 3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I have a problem: I am writing a program in Python 3.2 that requires that a loop run uninterrupted and separate from the rest of the program, but at the same time it must be able to send and receive data (such as a string) from the main part of the script.  The parts would work like this:

```
# Continuing loop (LOOP)
while True:
    data.read()
    if data[2] == "ff":
        string += data
    if request = True:
        SEND(string, MAIN)
        string = []

# Main program (MAIN)
hexValues = REQUEST(string, LOOP)
```

So, like having two processes of Python running at the same time but talking to each other.

Is this even possible?  If so, how should I do it?

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu GNU/Linux and Python 3.2.

Comment: I don't have time to write a sufficient answer, but have a look at the threading module: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module is for. You can also look at [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: I knew about threading before, but I read that I should avoid using threads in Python 3 because of something called GIL.  Is this still relevant?

Comment: @GrantVesely: It's FUD, you should ignore it. The GIL means that you can not implement multi-processor support with threads (which is something threads was never intended to do in the first place). That's all. It does not mean that you should not use threads for cases like yours, which is what threads *are* intended to be used for.